# Extract iTunes Config from iPod

Tags: itunes, ipod, ipod-classic

I recently had a hard drive failure on my laptop and I am in the middle of re-installing everything. I have hit a snag that I am at a loss how to fix.

Basically, I have been backing up my music to a NAS box on my network so I have not lost that I was pretty sure that I had been backing up the iTunes config as well but it appears not. I have an iPod classic that I regularly sync with iTunes and so I have a representation of playlists, star ratings, etc..

So my question is, can I reinstate my iTunes library from the information on my iPod?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a Bunch of iPod music recovery softwares you can search on Google, Some even give an option to export to iTunes library, hence maintaining the user ratings etc. I generally use [iPod Access](http://download.cnet.com/iPod-Access/3000-2140_4-10182021.html?tag=mncol;6) for recovery of music or video if I accidentally delete something.